# Função Impulso-Resposta no R

Tags: r

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao output da função `irf` do pacote `vars`.

Qual a diferença em relação ao *output* quanto aos argumentos `_cumulative = TRUE/FALSE_` e `_ortho = TRUE/ FALSE_`?

Outra coisa, o impulso sobre a variável é de 1%, 10% ou 1 desvio padrão? E onde posso escolher o valor do impulso?

Answer (score 1):

Ao que parece `ortho = TRUE/FALSE` serve para controlar uma possível autocorrelação entre as variáveis (ou seus erros), fazendo com que o efeito marginal seja "mais limpo". Isso é realizado internamente ajustando os impulsos por uma matriz que resulta da decomposição de cholesky da matriz de covariâncias dos erros.

Já `cumulative = TRUE/FALSE` permite que os efeitos marginais sejam ou não acumulados (um clássico `cumsum()`).

Quanto ao impulso, aparentemente é predefinido, e nessa função não teria como ser alterado. Pode ver, na função `Phi`, que é definido como `diag(K)`, onde `K` é o número de variáveis.

Maiores informações em (inglês): https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143296/77852

Pode ver os códigos das funções usando:

```
methods(irf)
getS3method("irf","varest")
vars:::.irf
vars:::Psi
methods(Psi)
getS3method("Psi","varest")
getS3method("Phi","varest")
```